# How to inject Bean of property within my context Bean?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to inject Bean of properties within context Bean.
(Spring-boot 2.7.3 / Java 11)

My `application.yml` is like below:

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    active: dev
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
keycloak:
  username: "local"
  password: "local"
---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: stg
keycloak:
  username: "stg"
  password: "stg"
---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod
keycloak:
  username: "prod"
  password: "prod"
```

and my `KafkaProducerConfig.java` code like below:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Component
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("keycloak")
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
  private final String username;
  private final String password;

  public KafkaProducerConfig(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

and finally I failed to inject within another class.

Actually, `UserDataProducer` class extended in a context bean class which means `UserDataProducer` class also instanciated by spring IoC Container as I know.

I also tried `@DependsOn` which doesn't work.

```java
@Slf4j
@DependsOn(value = {"KafkaProducerConfig"})
public class UserDataProducer {
  @Autowired
  KafkaProducerConfig kafkaProducerConfig;
  private final String topicName;
  public UserDataProducer() {
    log.info("===========================================================");
    log.info("Initializing UserDataProducer ...");
    System.out.println(kafkaProducerConfig.getPassword());
    log.info("===========================================================");
    
    // additional properties for transactional producing
    topicName = ProducerConfig.PRODUCER_PROPS.getProperty("default.topic");
  }
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding

Answer (score -2):

```
    @Slf4j
@Component
public class UserDataProducer {

  // use static initializer block to initialize your static fields
  // private static final Producer<String, Object> producer;
  // initialzer order : static{} -> instance block {} -> constructor 
  private final String topicName;
  public UserDataProducer(KafkaProducerConfig kafkaProducerConfig) {
    log.info("===========================================================");
    log.info("Initializing UserDataProducer ...");
    System.out.println(kafkaProducerConfig.getPassword());
    log.info("===========================================================");
    
    // additional properties for transactional producing
    topicName = ProducerConfig.PRODUCER_PROPS.getProperty("default.topic");
  }
```